# whats the difference between python 3.3 and 3.3m

Tags: python, python-3.3

What's the difference between python 3.3 and 3.3m

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 Raring and on my system I have python2.7 and python3.3 (I know the differences between 2 and 3)

But I also have installed python3.3m (and it's not a symlink to 3.3). So what does the `m` stand for?

Comment: "more better"? ... is this really a programming question?

Comment: what does `apt-cache show` say?

Comment: Seems to me like something to do with python module development. That's a guess though. Don't quote me.

Comment: This shouldn't have been closed. It is actually a relevant distinction! The `m` suffix means specifically a "pymalloc" build of Python, and it may mean that the ABI of `3.3` on your platform is not the same as the ABI of `3.3m`; extension modules must be built for the specific ABI in question. This means that `3.3` extension modules won't work with `3.3m` and vice-versa. The change to tag Python versions was proposed and accepted as [PEP-3149: ABI version tagged .so files](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/).

Comment: @nneonneo why not make this an answer?

Comment: @kojiro: Until recently, the question was closed. I will convert it to an answer now.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

`python3` is a symbolic link to `python3.3`

`python3.3` is a **hard link** to `python3.3m`

---

And as @nneonneo 's answer indicating, **The `m` suffix means specifically a "pymalloc" build of Python.** Then the links do what they do.

Comment: just for making the file name not same. no specific meaning. it's not another version of python.

Comment: But **why** does Ubuntu have to create this hard link? No other distribution does this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "No other distribution does this." Arch Linux does.

Comment: So why does ArchLinux create the link?

Answer (score 36):

The m suffix means specifically a "pymalloc" build of Python, and it may mean that the ABI of 3.3 on your platform is not the same as the ABI of 3.3m. Extension modules must be built for the specific ABI in question. This means that 3.3 extension modules won't work with 3.3m and vice-versa.

The change to tag Python versions was proposed and accepted as [PEP-3149: ABI version tagged .so files](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/).

Comment: And obviously this doesn't matter if you are dealing with pure-python modules. Thanks for the update, I was wondering if I will have to add yet another version of python to run my tests against. Still, as I am doing only pure-python modules, I will not have to care about the `m`-ones.